# What steps do I take to add my newly created Gem? And how can I access it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, c, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I just created [this](https://github.com/gotoAndBliss/aes_gem) standard skeleton of a gem.

In it I'm extending Ruby with C. [Using this tutorial](http://tenderlovemaking.com/2009/12/18/writing-ruby-c-extensions-part-1.html), I produced a very basic gem that performs a simple `hello_world` method.

But I'm not sure how to incorporate this into an app at this point.

Does anyone know what steps I need to take in order to install this gem in my existing Rails app? Then, once it is installed (I imagine with Bundler), how would one access the method of `hello_world` from within the Ruby environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bundler to install local gems and use them.

This can be achieved by

```
gem "foo", :path => "/path/to/foo"
```

in your case

```
   gem 'aes_gem', path: '/path/to/aes_gem'
```

Once you complete your gem, you can push into github or rubygems and specify the path accordingly

Comment: Any idea how I can access the methods within my gem?

Comment: You can call using as method in aes.c, Like hello_world("hello world")and change the method definition to return or print the "hello world" instead of defining it statically.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed your repository is missing the `.gemspec` file. Gemspecs define a "gem" and allow it to be installed and published using Rubygems. [This guide](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/)  to creating a gem, on rubygems.org, explains what a .gemspec file is and how to create it.

Once you have a gemspec file in your repo, you can [publish it to rubygems](http://guides.rubygems.org/publishing/) (so it can be installed on any computer), or use it directly from your filesystem. To include a gem from a local directory in a gemfile, the include line looks like this:

```
gem 'aes_gem', path: '/path/to/aes_gem'
```

Or if you just want to install it using `gem install`:

```
gem install /path/to/aes_gem.0.0.0.gem
```

Comment: Hmm.. but how can I execute the code from within my app?

Comment: As I can see from your test.rb, you should be able to access it as Aes.hello_world

Comment: First, you need to make sure that your code (at least, one file that you want to `require`) is in the `lib` directory of your gem. The lib directory will be added to ruby's load paths when the gem is installed. if your code is in the `aes.rb` file in the gem's lib direcory, and you have installed the gem, then you can require it with `require 'aes'`.